# Find the value of $P((X-Y)^2>5)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, independence

Suppose $X\sim N(0,1)$, $Y\sim N(0,9)$ and $X,Y$ are independent. Find the value of $P((X-Y)^2>5)$

What I am doing:

Let $U=X-Y$ which means $U\sim (0,10)$.

Therefore, we need $P(U^2 >5)$ or $P(U>\sqrt{5}) + P(U<-\sqrt{5}) $

or $P(\frac{U-0}{\sqrt10}>\frac{\sqrt(5)-0}{\sqrt10}) + P(\frac{U-0}{\sqrt10}<\frac{-\sqrt(5)-0}{\sqrt10})$

which is $P(Z>0.707) + P(Z<-0.707)$ = something (I'll use the Z- table).

Am I doing it right?

Comment: I assume that $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that

Comment: Your solution is right.